# xmemcached set error ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, memcached, xmemcached

I add to servers to xmemcached and try to set a few items. I get this exception

```
bar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:371)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:384)
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.impl.ArrayMemcachedSessionLocator.getSessionByKey(ArrayMemcachedSessionLocator.java:67)
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.impl.MemcachedConnector.findSessionByKey(MemcachedConnector.java:570)
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.impl.MemcachedConnector.send(MemcachedConnector.java:487)
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.sendCommand(XMemcachedClient.java:288)
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.fetch0(XMemcachedClient.java:617)
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.get0(XMemcachedClient.java:1030)
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.get(XMemcachedClient.java:988)
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.get(XMemcachedClient.java:999)
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.get(XMemcachedClient.java:1021)
at AxCacheEngine.Libs.AxMemcached.main(AxMemcached.java:33)
```

Here's the code:

```
MemcachedClientBuilder builder = new XMemcachedClientBuilder(AddrUtil.getAddresses(
            "127.0.0.1:11211 127.0.0.1:11311"
    ));
builder.setSessionLocator(new ArrayMemcachedSessionLocator(HashAlgorithm.ONE_AT_A_TIME));

MemcachedClient memcachedClient = builder.build();
System.out.println("Trying to get 1 milllion items");

int hugeItems = 0;
int normalItems = 0;
int totalCount = 0;

System.out.println(memcachedClient.set("foo",0,"bar"));
System.out.println(memcachedClient.set("bar",0,"baz"));
System.out.println(memcachedClient.set("yin",0,"yang"));
```

What could be the problem? Is there some issue with distribution strategy? I get this error when I try to get the items set from php-memcached.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your issue and I think that you cannot use the `ArrayMemcachedSessionAllocator` with the `One at a Time` hashing algorithm for 2 or more sessions.

According to the documentation the `ArrayMemcachedSessionAllocator` class locates Sessions as `hash(key) mod sessions.size()`.

And this number will be an index of an Arraylist in the code. In particular, this is the guilty line:

```
long start = this.getHash(size, key); //gets computed by ONE_AT_A_TIME hash % number of sessions
List<Session> sessions = sessionList.get((int) start); //this is where you get out of bounds
```

The problem is that `ONE_AT_A_TIME hash` can be negative. It is negative for `bar` (the source of the problem).

So if you have a negative hash value modulo 2 (number of servers), `start` is a negative value too.

On the other hand, `foo` has a positive hash value for `One_At_a_Time` and modulo 2 remains a positive value!

**Note**: The algorithm works perfectly fine if you have one server (as any number % 1 is positive).

So, I think you just can't use this hashing algorithm with the `ArrayMemcachedSessionAllocator` class for 2 or more servers.

Comment: you are right. I then just used Math.abs on the result. And resulting server location is the exact one give by php's hashing algo